# long running database operations in .net

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a delimited file that I use to insert/update records in a sql server table via a .net application.
The file has about 80000 records and is processed daily.
My question: is it safe or even sensible to keep the connection to the db open while i spin through each of the 80000 rows or should I be closing the connection and reopening with each iteration of the loop?  That sounds cumbersome in itself.
However, I am concerned about holding an open connection for a long time, holding locks and using up memory unnecessarily.
What would be a more scalable, safe and sensible way to do this?

Comment: Please define 'for a long time': hours? Is this running inside one transaction? What locks are you referring to? Where are you using up memory, in sql or in the application server? I don't dare to ask to elaborate on more scalable and safe....

Comment: Currently with the sample i have for testing it just takes around an hour to finish.  But if the actual file grows when I move this to production it will be longer.  I am not using a single transaction.

Comment: Is your sqlserver maxed out? Could it handle one extra worker? Does order matter?

Comment: The table is in a db that is accessed by an enterprise app with about 10-15[sometimes more] users on average at any given time.  The enterprise db has its own scheduled tasks that run at different times of the day. I would assume that all of these are already causing a load on the sql server. My process needs to run as a scheduled task in windows.  I dont think the sql server is maxed out but I just dont want to take the chance.  I guess order does not matter.

Comment: read every single line, put each line in a msmq, spin-up a worker which reads the queue and stores into sql, keep adding workers as long as the process time decreases...workers can be threads on a appserver, or process on different appservers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, no you should not open/close the connection every row.  For 80,000 rows, that will take forever and will just add to the overhead.  You could consider batching the rows (reset the connection say every 10-500 rows). Fortunately, there is a better option:

Secondly, the proper way to insert/update that many rows into a database from a .Net application, is to use the [SQLBulkCopy methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize.aspx), and not the INSERT or UPDATE commands.  You should use SQLBulkCopy to load the data rows into a holding/staging table, and then use a SQL Stored Procedure to do the Insert/Update to the actual table(s), en-mass.

If you are concerned about the sustained load of the SQLBulkCopy, it has batching options built-in.

Using this technique, the initial upload of data should be *at least* 5x faster, and the actual table Insert/Updates should only be a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I once had a need to import data.  But I had to run some mini business rules on it.
Also in my requirement was to import as many rows as possible, but if anything failed, log it (but don't fail the entire import).

I wrote the sample below.

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/bulk-insert-example-using-an-idatareader-to-strong-dataset-to-sql-server-xml/

I pass down N number of records (N = 1000 for example) as ~xml to a stored procedure.

N should be configurable, to find a "sweet spot".  But one at a time is too slow, and 80,000 at one time seems to many.  1,000 (rows) x 80 "runs".... is a good starting point, IMHO.

So if your import is "dumb", then the previously suggested "SQLBulkCopy" may be the best way.
But if you have any checking or validation, then my sample might be a good suggestion.

.......

Another option:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx
bcp.exe

But that isn't really "dot net code".

Comment: So that was a VS2005 example.  Man, I'm getting old!  If I did that today, I would.  (1) Use VS2010 (at least).  (2) Change the EnterpriseLibrary v5, which would already have OleDb abilties out of the box and (3) Change my TSQL to not use OPENXML, but rather "nodes" syntax.  Example here: http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2007/06/shredding-xml-in-sql-server-2005.html